# Laravel - How validate max size of an image that exceed upload_max_filesize directive

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm using ajax request to send an image to server and returning immediately some data. (for test)

```
return [
  'photo' => Request::file('avatar'),
  'hasFile' => Request::hasFile('avatar'),
  'extension' => Request::file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension(),
  'size' => Request::file('avatar')->getClientSize(),
  'maxFileSize' => Request::file('avatar')->getMaxFilesize()
];
```

When image is less than **upload_max_filesize** directive, i have this response:

```
{"photo":{},"hasFile":true,"extension":"jpg","size":900498,"maxFileSize":2097152}
```

When image is greater than **upload_max_filesize** directive, i have this response:

```
{"photo":{},"hasFile":false,"extension":"jpg","size":0,"maxFileSize":2097152}
```

Look at `size` on last response. How i can validate it?

Comment: You need to use size instead of max to validate file size.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use size instead of max to validate file size.
max:value

> Blockquote
>   The field under validation must be less than or equal to a maximum value. Strings, numerics, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule
>   So we go to the Size rule:

size:value

> Blockquote
>   The field under validation must have a size matching the given value. For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

get the file size

```
$filesize = Input::file('photo')->getSize();
```

push the file size in the data to be validated

```
$data['filesize'] = $filesize;
```

your rule should look like this
    $rules = ['filesize' => 'size:max size in KB'];

you can also do this when the file size == false, before call the form validation

```
 $file_size    Input::file('avatar')->getSize() // false
 if ($filesize){
  //  continue 
 }
```

I think this approach is a lot easier.

Hope this help.

Comment: the correct rule to this case is `max:value`, but look to my problem: i can't access size value of uploaded whenever the file exceed the directive value. How i'll validate?

Comment: file with less then upload_max_filesize directive: `Input::file('avatar')->getSize() // 900498`

Comment: file greater then upload_max_filesize directive: `Input::file('avatar')->getSize() // false`

Comment: where are you setting that directive?

Comment: as default, at php.ini, *upload_max_filesize = 2MB*

Comment: if you want to do server validation you will need to change the value to get the file size, also set post_max_size as well. Or you can check if the value == false return error.

Comment: You are touching at the core of my problem: i don't wanna change default value and image is optional, so, if `Request::hasFile('avatar') == false` i should not return an error

Comment: Now, in my position, i'm not able to send a feedback to user from the server for size exceeding max size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88242/discussion-between-mdamia-and-alexandre-thebaldi).

Answer (score 0):

As I know you could be able to  validate a type of image by client side script but in case of size its completely server side  validation .

Comment: i'm validating the size and type on client. but isn't sufficient. look to my problem: i can't access size value of uploaded whenever the file exceed the directive value. How i'll validate?